# CSS Float on resize: unwanted pushdown of element (cause of margin/padding) (responsive design)

Tags: css, resize, media-queries, floating

I have following problem:

My header consists of the menu, some news sliding with flexslider and a search input:

The problem: when I manually RESIZE the browser, or reload it with smaller width; the right element jumps down (pushdown because no space left)

Here is a small test:

http://jsfiddle.net/FFVzh/

Does someone know a solution for this? The header should be responsive, without pushdown of right element.

hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a percentage for the horizontal component of the `#right` margin, the margin will scale with the width of the window.

```
#right {
  background:yellow;
  float:right;
  width:18%;
  margin: 10px 1% 3px 0;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick answer; on my demo it works, but on my real code, a percentage margin / padding doensn't do the trick :( it still jumps because no space is available :(

Comment: however, i fixed it now, but now the #right element becomes much smaller than the left one, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have set your margin for the right element in pixels, you need to use `%` and it will work, otherwise use padding instead of margin an `box-sizing:border-box`